# How can I get the location of an imported package in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm doing package debugging and I forgot how to get the exact location of an imported package. I know there is a function to do this, but I forgot what it was.

Comment: try : `package_name.__file__`

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for:

```
import inspect

inspect.getfile(obj)
```